Infer return type from parameter and a map
I have the following types. It incorrectly infers the returnType. The expectation is that cityAttractions should have a type error on its return statement as it returns a string instead of an array of string.
typescript playground
interface Tool<RESULT = any> {
  returnType?: RESULT;
}

type ToolCallWithInferredReturnType<ToolsRecord extends Record<string, Tool>> = {
  [ToolName in keyof ToolsRecord]: ToolsRecord[ToolName]['returnType']
}

export type OnToolCall<ToolsRecord extends Record<string, Tool> = Record<string, Tool>> = 
  (args: { toolCall: { toolName: string } }) => ToolsRecord extends Record<string, Tool>
    ? ToolCallWithInferredReturnType<ToolsRecord>[typeof args['toolCall']['toolName']] 
    : void | Promise<unknown> | unknown;

type Tools = {
  weather: {
    returnType: string;
  }
  cityAttractions: {
    returnType: string[];
  }
}

export const onToolCall: OnToolCall<Tools> = ({ toolCall }) => {
  if (toolCall.toolName === 'weather') {
    return 'Weather information was shown to the user.';
  }
  if (toolCall.toolName === 'cityAttractions') {
    return "Attractions was shown to the user."; // type error should be throw here
  }

  throw Error("")
}


If you want more engagement with the question, you should greatly simplify it to a minimal example that has the bug.

Thanks for the feedback! I have removed zod and tool parameter types.

unknown is the top type in TS. Any union with unknown is just unknown.  You wrote something like  T[K]['returnType'] | (void | Promise<unknown> | unknown) but that's just unknown. Why do you have that in there unless you'd like to accept all values?

see prev comment. If I were to rewrite this so it works I'd make it look like this version but there's no unknown in there. Please [edit] so that we're not using void and unknown  and then we can see if this is answerable.

I was aiming for something like this in JavaScript ToolsRecord[ToolName]['returnType'] || (void | Promise<unknown> | unknown). Use the returnType if it exists, otherwise just assume it is (void | Promise | unknown). Alternatively, (void | Promise | returnType) should also work.

So then does this version meet your needs? You need a generic in there, since in your version, typeof args['toolCall']['toolName'] is a longwinded way of saying string. And you need to rewrite the implementation for TS to type check it; you can't use a series of if/else statements to check generics (without something like ms/TS#33014 being implemented). If that fully addresses the question I can write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Seems close but it doesn't seem to work with a function like const onToolCall: OnToolCall<Tools> = ({ toolCall }) => {...}

I don't understand... my link here shows it working. What specifically is the issue? ... isn't helping me understand.

Try this link. It throws an error when its incorrect and when it should also be working.

Hmm, I addressed that in my comment: "And you need to rewrite the implementation for TS to type check it; you can't use a series of if/else statements to check generics (without something like ms/TS#33014 being implemented)." It's a missing feature in TypeScript. Am I missing something?

Nope. If that's the case, then I guess this depends on the feature being implemented in TypeScript and should be the answer.

In order for this to work, you need OnToolCall<T> to be a generic function, so the return type of OnToolCall<T> can depend on the type of the toolName subproperty in the argument.  This doesn't happen merely by referring to the type like typeof args['toolCall']['toolName']; if args is just of type { toolCall: { toolName: string} }, then that type is a longwinded way of saying string. You can't get away from generics like that.
So let's say that the type of that toolName property is a generic type parameter K constrained to keyof T. Then OnToolCall<T> should be defined like this:
type OnToolCall<T extends Record<string, Tool>> =
  <K extends keyof T>(args: { toolCall: { toolName: K } }) =>
    ToolCallWithInferredReturnType<T>[K];

Now you can verify that callers see the desired behavior:
type Tools = {
  weather: {
    returnType: string;
  }
  cityAttractions: {
    returnType: string[];
  }
}

let onToolCall: OnToolCall<Tools> = ⋯;

const strArr = onToolCall({ toolCall: { toolName: "cityAttractions" } });
//    ^? const strArr: string[]
const str = onToolCall({ toolCall: { toolName: "weather" } });
//    ^? const str: string

So that looks good.

But note that you cannot implement onToolCall the way you were doing before, at least not without a type assertion:
onToolCall = ({ toolCall }) => { // error!
//~~~~~~~~ <-- Type 'string[] | string' is not assignable to 
//  type 'ToolCallWithInferredReturnType<Tools>[K]'
  if (toolCall.toolName === 'weather') {
    return 'Weather information was shown to the user.';
  }
  if (toolCall.toolName === 'cityAttractions') {
    return ["Attractions was shown to the user."]; 
  }
  throw Error("")
}

TypeScript is unable to use control flow narrowing (such as if/else blocks) to affect generic type parameters. You can check toolCall.toolName === 'weather', and that will narrow toolCall.toolName, but it doesn't affect the generic type parameter K at all. And so TypeScript can't verify that string is assignable to ToolCallWithInferredReturnType<Tools>[K].
There is a longstanding open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#33014 to allow this to work, and there's been some progress toward implementing it, but currently (as of TypeScript 5.5) it's not part of the language.
Perhaps in some future version of TypeScript, the code above will just start working as-is. Right now if you want to write a function that returns a generic indexed access type, you'll need to implement by indexing into an object.  Like this:
onToolCall = ({ toolCall }) => ({
  weather: 'Weather information was shown to the user.',
  cityAttractions: ["Attractions was shown to the user."]
}[toolCall.toolName]); // okay

That's essentially the same thing as the previous implementation, but this one is doing a lookup instead of if/else.  And if you implement it improperly then you'll get the expected error:
onToolCall = ({ toolCall }) => ({
  weather: 'Weather information was shown to the user.',
  cityAttractions: "Attractions was shown to the user."
}[toolCall.toolName]) // error!
//   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.    

although that error is shown on the whole expression. If you want an error whose source is easier to see, you can write it in multiple statements:
onToolCall = ({ toolCall }) => {
  const t: ToolCallWithInferredReturnType<Tools> = {
    weather: 'Weather information was shown to the user.',
    cityAttractions: "Attractions was shown to the user." // error!
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  }
  return t[toolCall.toolName]
}

Playground link to code

Thanks for helping me debug this TypeScript problem!
